Is there any way to create a sequential storage space on Windows?
I want to create a storage space out of VHDX files for purposes I won't get into here, and I need Windows to write files to the VHDX files sequentially. As it stands, Windows spreads the data more or less evenly across all drives.
If I have 10 drives and I write, say a 10GB file, then windows will write 1GB on each drive. I want it to write that file on a single drive until it fills it up and only then start writing to other drives.

Is this a question about Windows Storage Spaces ?

@Silbee yes. Ignore the text from this point forward. Stack overflow is stupid and won't allow me to write a simple "Yes" comment to answer your question because a minimum character limit.

For sequential writing, Windows Storage Spaces is not the solution.
You should rather use a Spanned Volume.
Spanned drives are utilized sequentially, meaning data won't be
written to the second hard drive until the first hard drive is full.
See for example the article
How to Combine Multiple Hard Drives into One Volume,
section "Method #2- How to Combine Two Hard Drives/SSD Drives with Disk Management":


Go to Start.
Type diskmgmt.msc into the search box to launch the Disk Management Tool.
Before proceeding, make sure that both drives are unformatted and do not have any partitions. Also, make sure they are dynamic by right
clicking them and selecting convert to a dynamic disk.
Right click on the drive that you want to combine. Now select New Spanned Volume or New Stripped Volume from the drop-down menu.
The New Spanned/Stripped Volume wizard will pop up. Click next once it appears.
Add the second drive (you can add multiple).
Select a letter for your new drive, format the new volume and complete the wizard.
The Windows Disk Management Tool will now show this new volume that you created listed at the top. The two drives that you combined will
be highlighted in purple.



Another article with more screenshots is
How to combine multiple hard drives into one volume on Windows 10.

I tried but it won't allow me to change the disks to dynamic. The option is grayed out in disk management and using disk part just gives me a generic "operation not supported" error.

Yes, I found out that detachable storage can't be made Dynamic. You will need to attach it to a VM, where it will look like an internal disk, and do it there.

I need the ability to mount and browse the files.

Try to format as Dynamic in a VM, detach and try in Windows.

I did. The disks show up as invalid in disk manager.

This solution then doesn't work for VHDX. Sorry. There might not exist a configuration that fulfills your criteria with VHDX.

I was worried you might say that
